# changing const values via pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I exploit the order of memory allocation on the stack during variable creation to change the value of a const int .Here's the program:

```
//compiled this using C++14 standard on cpp.sh and on MinGW32
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int c=5;
    const int a(c);
    cout<<(&c+1)<<endl<<&a<<endl;   //Verifying if the addresses are the same
    (*(&c+1))++;
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Turns out that I can change the value of the const variable. Am I trespassing into a domain of undefined behaviour or is it allowed?

I think that the program stores const variables in the same way as normal ones. The compiler is the one which actively prevents me from changing the values when I try to access it directly. I mean to say that the compiler differentiates between const and non-const variables, not the stack itself (on which the variables are stored).

If I can do this, how will I be able to ensure the const-ness of a variable if I mistakenly point to a const variable's location?

Also, as a side question, does this same program work in other languages too (after making the necessary changes to the syntax, of course)?

Note: this is a bit different from the other questions out there on changing value of consts via pointers. They used explicit conversion to int* to convert the pointer to int* from const int *.

Comment: `&c+1` is not a valid pointer, so you are not allowed to dereference that.

Comment: "Am I trespassing into a domain of undefined behaviour or is it allowed?" -- what do *you* think?!

Comment: As for whether this works in other languages, well, can you try and see what happens in JavaScript and in ML?

Comment: @BoPersson It's a valid pointer, but it must not be dereferenced.

Comment: Using `const` keyword could allow the compiler to do optimisation by assuming that it is never changed, e.g. solving some calculations at compile time. So if casting  from const to non const, or modifying a const variable is valid, depends on if the value was const before. E.g. if you pass a non const value by reference to a function and the parameter is `const`.

Comment: btw: If you also print `&c+1 == &a` you might get a surprise.

Comment: Turn off optimisation on cpp.sh, and you'll get crazy results. The addresses will be equal, but `a` will be 6 and `c` will be 5. That's what happens with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Is this because of the footnote in §5.7/4 which says *"An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose"* and because the paragraph allows pointers to one-past-the-last-element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Turns out that I can change the value of the const variable. Am I trespassing into a domain of undefined behaviour or is it allowed?

The former, and as you know UB means anything goes.

> I think that the program stores const variables in the same way as normal ones.

It can. Sometimes, it does. Not that you should depend on that.

> The compiler is the one which actively prevents me from changing the values when I try to access it directly. I mean to say that the compiler differentiates between const and non-const variables, not the stack itself (on which the variables are stored).
>   If I can do this, how will I be able to ensure the const-ness of a variable if I mistakenly point to a const variable's location?

Well, unless you venture into the land of UB, there's no problem. And if you do, there's no recourse.

> Also, as a side question, does this same program work in other languages too (after making the necessary changes to the syntax, of course)?

Sure, you can write something very similar in all languages allowing direct memory access, in most others you can go over libraries and still do those shenanigans.